# mvn dependency:copy-dependencies removes the versions

Tags: maven-2, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm using "mvn dependency:copy-dependencies" to get all sources of the dependencies my project uses.
I use it from command line, so it looks like this:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -Dclassifier=sources -DincludeScope=compile
```

It works fine except of a small problem: For some reason the version is removed by this plugin. So instead of commons-logging-1.1.1-sources.jar, I'm getting commons-logging-sources.jar

The documentation says that "stripVersion" argument should effect this behavior, but the default value is false. Moreover, I tried to set it explicitly and it didn't help.

I'm using apache-maven-2.2.1 with jdk1.6.0_21

Thanks,
Tarlog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the root cause of a problem. Somewhere in the parent of parent of parent of ... my pom, stripVersion was set to true.
I didn't know about it and anyway thought that setting the system property must override the xml. I even tried to put this property in my pom and it still didn't help. Somehow, the parent pom stayed the dominant one, so I thought that the property doesn't work.

When I ran with -X param I saw it no changing despite my configuration, so I started digging in the parent poms unless I found the problem.

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 5):

That's very strange, you can see in the source ([Mojo](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/dependency/CopyDependenciesMojo.java?revision=732368&view=markup), [Parent Mojo](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/dependency/AbstractFromDependenciesMojo.java?revision=732368&view=markup), [DependencyUtil](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/dependency/utils/DependencyUtil.java?revision=732368&view=markup)) that stripVersion does what it says it does.

Several possibilities:

a) Are you using the current version of the dependencies plugin?

Either configure your pom

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

or use the fully qualified goal name:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:copy-dependencies
```

b) `stripVersion` is the parameter name in XML configuration. The command line version is

```
-Dmdep.stripVersion=false
```

Try using that.

Comment: Well, I found the problem. Somewhere in the parent of parent of parent of my pom stripVersion was set to true. I didn't think that someone added this configuration since I thought that none is using it. And anyway I thought that system properties should override the xml configuration.

Comment: @tarlog no, pom config always wins over system property.